# Conceptual paradox with resistance in loop/node analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, power-dissipation

There are loop/mesh analysis and node analysis corresponding to Kirchhoff’s voltage law (KVL) and Kirchhoff’s current law (KCL), respectively.

Let's consider three elements, R,L,C, connected **serially** in the simplest way to some external voltage source.
With KVL and a charge variable \$q\$, we have \$(-\omega^2L+\frac{1}{C}+j\omega R)q(\omega)=v_\mathrm{ext}\$.
Let's consider three elements, R,L,C, connected **parallelly** in the simplest way to some external current source. With KCL and a flux variable \$\phi\$, we have \$(-\omega^2C+\frac{1}{L}+\frac{j\omega}{R})\phi(\omega)=i_\mathrm{ext}\$.

We see that such a resistor in the KVL of an AC simple RLC circuit can lead to a term proportional to \$j\omega R\$, which becomes a term proportional to \$\frac{j\omega}{R}\$ in KCL. *And all other terms are **real**.*
**(Surely, if you divide or multiply these equations by \$j\omega\$, you get the impedances like \$j\omega L,\frac{1}{j\omega C},R\$.)**

We know resistance entails dissipation, which is ***naturally related to imaginary terms***. So I don't think these equation forms are meaningless. I hope to understand.
However, the imaginary \$\frac{j\omega}{R}\$ term in node analysis KCL seems to be smaller and smaller as the resistance increases. It appears somewhat counterintuitive. How to understand this?

Comment: Please post an example schematic and your workings.

Comment: Capacitors present as a lower impedance path to higher frequency signals (and an open circuit to DC signals). Inductors present as a higher impedance path to higher frequency signals (and a short circuit to DC signals). Are you asking for physical intuition for these rules of thumb?

Comment: Resistors have no frequency dependence on their impedance ideally... only capacitors and inductors

Comment: ......"will lead to a term proportional to jwR...." ??? Please, demonstrate this statement with an example.

Comment: @LvW Updated. Please kindly let me know your comment.

Comment: @Andyaka Updated. Please kindly let me know your comment.

Comment: @vicatcu Updated. Please kindly let me know your comment.

Comment: No circuit and no derivation. It wasn't worth coming back.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, I mentioned it's the simplest three R, L, C serially or parallelly connected. I guess it's OK to omit the circuit and derivation? No offense, I really want some help.

Comment: I get that, you write a KVL in series R_L_C with /$V_in/$ source. the equation is incorrect. for dissipation you should write the power on the resistor that is \$P_res =  V_r X I_r^* \$ then ask your question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although those are imaginary terms, and you are expressing your equations in terms of flux and charge, which makes things a bit confusing.

Note that in one equation you are calculating a voltage. In a voltage equation resistance implies dissipation.

In the other equation you are calculating a current. In a current equation conductance implies dissipation.

You always have to keep track of your units.

Comment: It's great that someone finally understand what I mean! Thank you, again. Let me think about your answer.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. It's also basically related to the two expressions of dissipation power, \$i^2R\$ and \$v^2/R\$. But I still feel somewhat confused that the dissipation or imaginary term goes very large when we have a more and more perfect conducting wire (\$R\$ goes down). Naively, a perfect conducting wire is dissipationless.

Comment: No. If R goes to zero the conductance goes to infinity. Infinite conductance means no dissipation. Unless you somehow manage to put a voltage across it, of course. That an abstract *imaginary term* grows means nothing unless you take in consideration the units that that imaginary term represents.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your concerns...

As @vicatu wrote:  Resistors have no frequency dependence on their impedance ideally... only capacitors and inductors.

Think of a capacitor as two metal plates, suspended one above the other, separated by air. Connect a battery's positive terminal to one of the plates, and its negative terminal to the other.  Is there current flow?  No. This is the limit case where frequency goes to zero for a capacitor - no current.

Now think about a length of wire, connecting the same two battery terminals - you'd get near infinite current flow (it's a dead short). Now wrap that wire around a wooden pole.  That's a simple inductor now.  Would you expect the (infinite) current from the battery to change?  No. That's the limit case for an inductor as the frequency goes to zero.

Comment: Please see my update. I understand these basics.